# Pairwise comparisons by subsetting or by custom contrasts and the differing treatment of *S*

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, contrasts

What's going on here?

```
data.2
         subj phon f.amp
    1     1    V   100
    2     2    V    60
    3     3    V   124
    4     4    V    42
    5     5    V   210
    6     6    V   104
    7     7    V   150
    8     1    ʔ    92
    9     2    ʔ    33
    10    3    ʔ    92
    11    4    ʔ    32
    12    5    ʔ    90
    13    6    ʔ    65
    14    7    ʔ   105
    15    1    h   142
    16    2    h    72
    17    3    h   141
    18    4    h    60
    19    5    h   268
    20    6    h   134
    21    7    h   145
```

Pairwise comparison of levels PHON<sub>V</sub> and PHON<sub>h</sub> by running ANOVA on the pertinent subset of data:

```
library(lme4)
anova(lmer(f.amp~phon+(1|subj),data.2[which(data.2[,2]!="ʔ"),]))
   Analysis of Variance Table
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
   phon  1 2113.1  2113.1  9.8144
```

Pairwise comparison of the same levels by direct definition of contrast coefficients; different resulting *F*-ratio:

```
contrasts(data.2[,2],1)=matrix(c(-1,0,1),nrow=3)
contrasts(data.2[,2])
    [,1]
  V   -1
  ʔ    0
  h    1
anova(lmer(f.amp~phon+(1|subj),data.2))
   Analysis of Variance Table
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
   phon  1 2113.1  2113.1  1.2566
```

Since *df*<sub>PHON</sub>, *SS*<sub>PHON</sub> and *MS*<sub>PHON</sub> are the same for both analyses; and since *F*<sub>PHON</sub> = *MS*<sub>PHON</sub> / *MS*<sub>PHON x *S*</sub>, I deduce that the analyses differ regarding the handling of *S*.

Any ideas as to how and why precisely?